# How do I fix a problem where adding a new React Router path causes unexpected issues

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

In the following code, I have a commented out line. Everything works just fine as it is, however when I uncomment the line, I get some weird behaviour. The target of the path suddenly seems to render two copies and any html links to the visit path no longer seem to work from the target page. I have tried rearranging the order of paths but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I am also using redux and it's possible that the problem is there but I'm just learning with redux so I'm not sure where to start looking.

```
  const App = () => (
  <main>
    <div id="App">
      <SideNav pageWrapId={"page-wrap"} outerContainerId={"App"} />
      <div id="page-wrap">
        <Route path="/visit/:location" component={Location} />
        {/* <Route path="/:location" component={Location} /> */}
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/visit" component={Visit} />
        <Route exact path="/give" component={Give} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route exact path="/media" component={Media} />
        <Route exact path="/connect" component={Connect} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
);
```

If someone could point me at least in a direction to look, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following case, the second route will render on every case, `:location` is a wildcard, it matches to every route you enter, since your not wrapping with `<Switch>` element all matching route will render,

learn more about the switch from the [link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)

```
<Route path="/visit/:location" component={Location} />
<Route path="/:location" component={Location} />
```

### Recommended Change

```
const App = () => (
  <main>
    <div id="App">
      <SideNav pageWrapId={"page-wrap"} outerContainerId={"App"} />
      <div id="page-wrap">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/visit/:location" component={Location} />
          <Route path="/visit" component={Visit} />
          <Route path="/give" component={Give} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/media" component={Media} />
          <Route path="/connect" component={Connect} />
          <Route path="/:location" component={Location} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
);
```

Comment: Yep solved the problem. I thought it was something like that but just couldn't work it out in my head. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When your `<Route path="/:location">` is at the top, then all your routes below that line will be matching that route. So, in `/visit` page, `visit` will be route param, in the `/give` page `give` will be route param and so on.
And all of your components will be rendered due to that fact.
I suggest you move `<Route path="/:location">` route to the bottom or change route name.
You are also not using `<Switch>`. Wrap your routes around `<Switch>` component.